# Hibernate - AttributeOverride default value when using Embedded

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

How to override @Column columnDefinition in case of using @Embedded in Hibernate?
To be more specific there is an example:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "isnettogross", column = @Column(name = "isnettogross", columnDefinition="char(1) default 1", nullable = false))})
public ParentGrossNetTransformVariables grossNetTransform;
```

and class ParentGrossNetTransformVariables:

```
@Embeddable
public class ParentGrossNetTransformVariables {
    @Column(name = "isnettogross", columnDefinition="char(1) default 0", nullable = false)
    public boolean isNet2GrossTransform;
```

as i use:

```
lConf.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
```

the changes in database are applied automaticly. Now I need to add ParentGrossNetTransformVariables in multiple entities but with **different default** value of "isnettogross" so that I try to use @AttributeOverrides but it doesnt work. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming "it doesn't work" as the changes made to column names not being reflected in the database.

`hbm2ddl.auto=update` does not update the schema. So changes you make to the column names does not get reflected in the database.

Change it to `create` so that it re-creates the schema based on the changes made, if any.

**UPDATE:**

Use `insertable=false` attribute along with the `columnDefintion` in your embeddable class, i.e.

`@Column(name = "isnettogross", columnDefinition="char(1) default 0", nullable = false, insertable=false)`

and the entity class,

`@AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "isnettogross", column = @Column(name = "isnettogross", columnDefinition="char(1) default 1", nullable = false, insertable=false))})`

This ignores the column of interest in the INSERT statement that is fired, thereby inserting the default value configured.
The same goes for `updatable`, so you might wanna use that too based on your use case.

**LATEST:**

I'm quite puzzled as to how it isn't working in your code. I have tried and tested; and it's working fine.

I have attached the code too just in case you wanna have a look and cross verify.

```
@Entity
public class Demo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name="flag", column=@Column(name="MainFlag", columnDefinition="char(1) default 1", insertable=false))
    private Misc misc;

    private Misc misc2;

    // Getters and setters



@Embeddable
public class Misc {

    @Column(name="flag", columnDefinition="char(1) default 0", insertable=false)
    private boolean flag;

    // Getters and setters
```

The code to test is a simple session.save() which generated the query

```
Hibernate: select hibernate_sequence.nextval from dual
Hibernate: insert into Demo (id) values (?)
```

Attaching the values persisted in the database as well :D

[image]

Comment: The column "isnettogross" in database is the new one and when the code is executed, it creates it. "It doesnt work" means that default value for "isnettogross" is not overridden and it stays 0 (look at class ParentGrossNetTransformVariables above)

Comment: The updated answer should solve your problem. Give it a shot :)

Comment: Ok, it took me some time but finally I checked it and the AttributeOverrides in the way You used above does not change default value of entity. The default value of attribute "isnettogros" is always false (char (1) default 0) as it appears in the Embedded class. The question is still opened as I have not found the answer

Comment: Adding a sample code that you can test separately to ensure the defaults are being picked/persisted as expected. If it still doesn't work then I really wonder why!! (Sorry for the bad naming BTW)

Comment: I used Oracle DB by the way to validate this scenario. Saying just in case, the underlying database architecture causes the output to be different.

Comment: Hmm I cant use insertable=false in the way You used it as I need this attribute to be insertable. I just wanted to change default value of attribute when the ALTER statement is created to add new column. Anyway I tested with insertable=false and for me It does not change the default value but I dont want to dig into it as I dont want it to be insertable=false